# CGI Calling Jar from html

Tags: java, html, batch-file, jar, cgi

I need to call a jar from an html. I have been calling C++ exes' using a line like this:

```
<a href="/cgi-bin/my.exe"> calling c++</a>
```

So I thought I would make a batch program and call it from the html file like this:

```
<a href="/cgi-bin/my.bat"> calling jar from a batch script </a>
```

where my.bat is just the following line:

```
java -jar my.jar
```

Somehow, when I click the link, instead of running the batch file as I want, a dialog appears asking me to save my.bat. Can someone explain what is going on?

I am running xampp on windows XP/Vista.

Solved:  I put a header and got it to run:

```
@echo off
echo Content-Type: text/plain
echo.
"c:/full_path/javaw.exe" -jar my.jar
```

Comment: probably the apache won't accept BAT as a cgi executable extension and thus just deliver the bat file?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I put a header on the batch file

Comment: Thanks Stefan, it is a good hint which lead to the right solution.